Do we need swap axes when combining GCN and CNN layers in pytorch?
I would like to add a GCN layer with a given adjacency matrix at the beginning of a 1D convolutional autoencoder. It seems for the 1DCNN each batch of data is of dimension (batch_size, number_features, number_nodes (vector dimension)) while for GCN it requires  (batch_size, number_node,snumber_features ). So do we need to swap axes for torch tensors when combining the two. I have torch code that works by swaping axes (see the forward function) but it seems very strange to me. Is there a better to do that?
class ConvAutoencoderGCN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,num_nodes,n_features):
    super(ConvAutoencoderGCN, self).__init__()

    self.num_nodes = num_nodes
    self.n_features = n_features
    
    self.gcn1 = GCNConv(n_features, 1)
      
    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv1d(1, 16, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=2),   # [batch, 16, 128, 128]
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=4, stride=8),                  # [batch, 16, 64, 64]
        nn.Conv1d(16, 32, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=0),  # [batch, 32, 64, 64]
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=4, stride=8),                  # [batch, 32, 32, 32]
        nn.Conv1d(32, 1, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=2),   # [batch, 64, 32, 32]
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),                  # [batch, 64, 16, 16]
    )

    # Flattening layer
    self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
    self.unflatten = nn.Unflatten(1, (1, 128))

    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose1d(1, 32, 3, stride=4, padding=0, output_padding=1),  # [batch, 32, 32, 32]
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.ConvTranspose1d(32, 32, 3, stride=4, padding=0, output_padding=1),  # [batch, 32, 32, 32]
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.ConvTranspose1d(32, 16, 3, stride=4, padding=0, output_padding=1),  # [batch, 16, 64, 64]
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.ConvTranspose1d(16, 1, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1),  # [batch, 1, 128, 128]
        nn.Sigmoid()
    )

def forward(self, x):
    x = torch.swapaxes(x, 1, 2)
    x = self.gcn1(x, this_edge_index, this_edge_weight)
    x = torch.swapaxes(x, 1, 2)
    x = self.encoder(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.unflatten(x)
    x = self.decoder(x)
    return x


using torch.swapaxes is fine, although x = x.permute(0,2,1) is more common syntax. That said, I see an issue with your tensor sizes. You say the GCN takes an input of size (batch_size, number_nodes, number_features), but this is not the case according to the torch geometric documentation. Docs say the input should be a node tensor of shape (n_nodes, features) and an edge tensor of shape (2, n_edges). This is typically how graphs are batched

You need to figure out a way to get the GCN node tensor into a format compatible with Conv1d. If all your graphs have the same number of nodes, you can reshape from (n_nodes, features) to (bs, n_nodes_per_graph, features). But if you have heterogenous node count, you can't do this. If your graphs have varying number of nodes, you won't be able to use Conv1d without some headaches

@Karl, many thanks for the remind. In fact I have included the shape and edge tensor in the forward function x = self.gcn1(x, this_edge_index, this_edge_weight). However, it seems strange to me that the feature dimension is not in the same place in GCN and Conv1D cnn layer. I have a doublt if this would derease the performance of my trained neural network.
